# Register last name set empty string in shopware 6.5

Tags: validation, shopware6

I really need help relating shopware 6.5 register customization! I want to allow registration without last name, but we have validations in shopware6.5 that last name is required.

I have decorate registerRoute and set some default value for last name, but after success registration I want to set it empty string back, but I get validation error when update by repository update. How can I resolve this problem ? I know only the way by updating with Doctrine\DBAL\Connection by sql

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `last_name` column is not nullable in neither the `customer` nor the `customer_address` table. Best you can do is have it fallback to an empty string. In addition there's a `NotBlank` constraint added in the validation definition, which you will also have to remove, as it also denies empty strings.

You could [create a subscriber](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events) which listens to the various `framework.validation.*` events. There are a few for customers and addresses and there might be more. In the example I used those which immediately came to mind.

In your subscriber you can then remove the constraint. You may also set the `lastName` in the instance of `DataBag` to empty string as a fallback, if it is no non-empty string yet. Changing data of the `DataBag` in the validator is not ideal, so you might want to look for alternative events you could use to set an empty string as fallback (they will be different events for each type of data to be persisted though).

```php
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\BuildValidationEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class CustomerValdiationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'framework.validation.customer.create' => 'onBuildValidationEvent',
            'framework.validation.customer.update' => 'onBuildValidationEvent',
            'framework.validation.customer.profile.create' => 'onBuildValidationEvent',
            'framework.validation.customer.profile.update' => 'onBuildValidationEvent',
            'framework.validation.address.create' => 'onBuildValidationEvent',
            'framework.validation.address.update' => 'onBuildValidationEvent',
        ];
    }

    public function onBuildValidationEvent(BuildValidationEvent $event): void
    {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $definition = $event->getDefinition();

        if (!\array_key_exists('lastName', $definition->getProperties())) {
            return;
        }

        // remove `NotBlank` constraint
        $definition->set('lastName');

        if (empty($data->get('lastName'))) {
            $data->set('lastName', '');
        }
    }
}
```